# Rank of normal sheaf in singular varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a $n$-dimensional normal, singular projective variety (over the field of complex numbers), and let $Y$ be a subvariety of $X$ of dimension $k$. I know that, if $X$ was non-singular, than the normal sheaf $N_{Y\mid X}$ would have been free of rank $n-k$.

In the singular case, can I still say something about the rank of the normal sheaf? Do we have at least $\text{rank}(N_{Y\mid X})\leq n-k$ (I think so, but I've never worked with singular varieties)?

I'm in particular interested in the case  $Y$ a divisor (that is, a codimension $1$ subvariety): is his normal sheaf a line bundle, or can strange things happen?

Comment: It depends on what sort of divisor you're considering. A Cartier divisor? Yes, the normal sheaf is a line bundle, almost by definition. A Weil divisor? Bad things can happen - consider the ruling $V(y)$ of the cone $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y,z]/(z^2-xy)$.

Comment: Dear @KReiser, thanks for the reply! In my specific case $X$ was even $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial, therefore there should'nt be any problem. Btw, if you write an answer providing a proof (for the divisor case) I will happily accept it! (Also because I don't see why it should hold)

Answer (score 1):

If $i:Y\to X$ is a closed immersion so that $i(Y)$ is cut out by the sheaf of ideals $\mathcal{I}$, then $i^*(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2)$ (often denoted just $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2$ by abuse of notation) is the conormal sheaf. When $Y$ is a Cartier divisor, $\mathcal{I}$ is locally principal, and the conormal sheaf is a line bundle on $Y$. Here's why: $i^*(\mathcal{I})\cong i^*(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2)$ and $\mathcal{I}$, being locally principal, is a line bundle. Since the pullback of a line bundle is a line bundle, the conormal sheaf is a line bundle, and its dual, the normal sheaf, is also a line bundle.

More generally, for any closed immersion which is locally a complete intersection, the normal/conormal sheaves are vector bundles by the same argument.

---

As for your more general question about the general properties of the normal sheaf, the appropriate tool is the **conormal exact sequence**: given an immersion of schemes $i:Y\to X$ over some base $S$, there is a canonical exact sequence $$ N^\vee_{Y/X}\to i^*\Omega_{X/S} \to \Omega_{Y/S}\to 0$$ where the first term is the conormal sheaf. If the composite $Y\to S$ is smooth or formally smooth, this is exact on the left as well ([ref](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06BB)). This mostly invalidates your first paragraph. (If you're interested in more details, please leave a note - I am about to leave for a short time and figured it was better to get you most of your answer rather than make you wait.)